# Angular2 build process fails

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm trying to build  https://github.com/angular/angular master as described in the [build steps](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md). When I gulp build.js, I end up with this error:

```
gulp build.js
Dart SDK detected
[20:10:31] Using gulpfile ~/dvl/mongo/angular2/gulpfile.js
[20:10:31] Starting 'build/clean.js'...
[20:10:31] Starting 'build/clean.tools'...
[20:10:31] Finished 'build/clean.tools' after 1.34 ms
[20:10:31] Starting 'build.tools'...
[20:10:31] Starting '!build.tools'...
[20:10:31] Finished 'build/clean.js' after 174 ms
[20:10:31] Starting 'build.js.dev'...
[20:10:31] Starting 'build/clean.tools'...
[20:10:31] Finished 'build/clean.tools' after 853 μs
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(1,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
[20:10:33] '!build.tools' errored after 1.82 s
[20:10:33] TypeScript error: tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(1,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
    at Output.getError (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/output.js:191:19)
    at Output.diagnostic (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/output.js:238:25)
    at ProjectCompiler.inputDone (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/compiler.js:60:33)
    at CompileStream.end (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/main.js:52:31)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:199:16)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at /home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:965:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[20:10:33] 'build.tools' errored after 1.82 s
[20:10:33] Error: [object Object]
    at formatError (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at finish (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:53:5)
    at Gulp.onError (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:60:4)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
[20:10:33] 'build.js.dev' errored after 1.65 s
[20:10:33] Error: [object Object]
    at formatError (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at finish (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:53:5)
    at Gulp.onError (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:60:4)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
[20:10:33] 'build.js.dev' errored after 1.65 s
[20:10:33] Error: [object Object]
    at formatError (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at finish (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:53:5)
    at Gulp.onError (/home/me/dvl/mongo/angular2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:60:4)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(2,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(3,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(4,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(5,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(6,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
tools/broccoli/angular_builder.ts(7,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

I don't have protractor and Chrome Canary install but I don't think they're related. At least few weeks ago it was building fine without them.

I also tried to put require('typescript-require');(https://github.com/eknkc/typescript-require) into gulpfile here and there but wihout any success.

So your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix for this error was to manually install the type definitions:

```
cd tools 
tsd install
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @s.Daniel for help,
i summarize all my struggling with build angular2 on win machine:

**1. install bower dependency**
Run `bower install`  from root
If you ll see error like this
`bower angular#1.0.6 ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH` then you need to specify environment variable Path like this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

replace path with your folder's path to `git.exe`.

**2.   From your local repo go to folder   `angular\tools`  and run these commands from there:**
in order to install tool's dependencies,

```
npm install
tsd install
```

Without this commands you should see error like this:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'promise' or error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require' or whatever it looking for.
```

**3. From local repo root go to folder `angular\modules\angular2` and run the same command from step 2.**

```
npm install
tsd install
```

Without running this command have errors like that:
Error:

```
[DiffingTSCompiler]: Typescript found the following errors: 
angular2/manual_typings/globals.d.ts (8, 42): Cannot find name 'Promise'
```

.

here:[build angular 2 beta 7 on win 10](http://itsrendertime.blogspot.com/2016/02/building-angular-2-beta7-on-windows-10.html)

Comment: Just linking to your own library blog is not a good answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)